# Boot error - don't find NOOBS files

Tags: noobs

i buy RPi4 and tried to install raspbian with NOOBS, but didn't work :-(
It displayed MSGBOX: Files not found with the message "Cannot find the drive with NOOBS file."

And then on CLI...

[0.982514] print_req_error: I/O error, dev mmcblk0, sector 0

[0.982549] Buffer I/O error on dev mmcblk0, logical block 0, async page read

Recovery application crashed

Starting shell

sh: can't access tty; job control turned off

/#

Troubleshooting

1) Re-format SD card with official format tool (https://www.sdcard.org/downloads/formatter/index.html)

2) Re-format SD card with refus (https://rufus.ie/)

3) Update EPPROM (https://static.raspberrypi.org/files/rpi-boot-eeprom-recovery-2019-09-10-vl805-000137ab.zip)

4) Update EPPROM to BETA (https://github.com/raspberrypi/rpi-eeprom/tree/master/firmware/beta)

5) Change NOOBS >> PINN (https://sourceforge.net/projects/pinn/files/testing/pinn-332.zip/download)

6) Direct libreELEC install

7) ? Shoot myself ????? :-(

Please help!

Comment: up vote for trying to solve yourself and for a good description of your troubleshooting effort

Answer (score 1):

Don’t use noobs.

Flash ‘Raspbian with Desktop’ (no need to unzip) direct to sd card with Etcher.

https://www.raspberrypi.org/downloads/raspbian/

https://www.balena.io/etcher/